# Is it possible to add a custom shortcut in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, jupyter-notebook

I would like to add a markdown cell in Jupyter Notebook using a shortcut, since adding a new cell and changing it to Markdown cell takes so much steps and feels painstaking at times.

But it seems that there is no such shortcut; so now I'm searching for a way, if any, to add a custom shortcut in Jupyter Notebook.

Is it possible to define a custom shortcut?

Answer (score 2):

[Jupyter](http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Notebook/Custom%20Keyboard%20Shortcuts.html) has a way to customize keyboard shortcuts. However, I'm not sure if what you're asking is available. I don't find it that tedious to add a Markdown cell by quickly pressing `esc` `(a or b)` `m` `enter` in succession, where (a or b) is if you want the cell above or below the current cell.