# Insert a new Markdown cell?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, markdown, keyboard-shortcuts

I don't want to change the default cell type. I want to create / change a shortcut / menu item (if possible) to insert a markdown cell.

e.g. Run and insert Markdown cell below

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to add a custom shortcut in Jupyter Notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45389894/is-it-possible-to-add-a-custom-shortcut-in-jupyter-notebook)